# Data with Spaces in Database Are not fully Showing in Textbox

Tags: php, mysql

```
<input type="text" name="question"  required class="form-control" placeholder="Question"  value=<?php
$emid = $_GET['key1'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posses_ques WHERE id = '$emid'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['ques'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No Data Available";
}
?>
>
```

Comment: You should quote the value: `value="<?php ... ?>">`. However, I would recommend moving the PHP code to a function or something. Nesting PHP with HTML like that is not recommended since it makes the code super hard to read and can't be reused at all. Also, you are _wide open_ for [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Read up on how to use [prepared statements with placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidier solution and one that does not allow [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) might be something like this

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posses_ques WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['key1']):
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$x = 0;
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo '<input type="text" name="question' . $x . '" value="' . $row['ques']. ' required class="form-control" placeholder="Question" ';

        $x++;
    }
} else {
    echo "No Data Available";
}
```

Note also the unique `name` attribute. These need to be unique or you wont see all of them in the data returned to the scripts from a form

Comment: Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: It is my pleasure